# asyntasks dependencies

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an android program that have a asyntask. I would like that when these asyntask finalize depending of the result launch one asyntask  or other asyntask. I'm tryng with these code but I think it works despite it doesnt shows me the progress dialog of the primary asyntask. When I comment the if statement shows me the progress dialog of the first asyntask.
How could I do it? Why don't show the progress dialog of the first asyntask.

```
lanzaPing tarea = new lanzaPing(); 
tarea.execute(); //first asyntask 

    try {
        if (tarea.get()){
            Log.d(«PRUEBA», «El resultado es .... « + tarea.get());
            new tareaWOL().execute();
        }else
        {
            Log.d(«PRUEBA», «El resultado es .... « + tarea.get());

            new tareaPing().execute();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the if-statement in the first AsyncTasks "onPostExecute"-method. That should work.
(If that was what you were asking for)..